# I can’t find my debug window on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I’ve already tried finding it by debugging a program but the debug window still doesn’t open.  Also tried by activating it on view but it is greyed out. What can I do?

Here is a picture of the greyed out button.

Comment: Just add a breakpoint to your first activity and start in debug mode.  That should bring up the standard debug view.  Also, I think you could have answered this question yourself by reading other questions already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That’s the problem, I already tried that and it didn’t work, any other suggestions?

Comment: So you're saying that Android Studio just skipped the breakpoint?

Comment: It didn’t, instead of opening the debug window, it opened a build window

Comment: try to invalidate and restart android studio

Answer (score 1):

Go to the View option in android studio and click on it there is a option toolbar button click on it you find the new bar will appear at the bottom in that bar you can find out the bebug window

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes due to the cache memory Android Studio will behave in inappropriate manner. My suggestion is that go to **File --> Invalidate Caches/ Restart** or go to **Build--> clean or Rebuild project**.

If above option is for cleaning the cache memory and then  **Go to --> Run-->Debug**.

There you can find the debug the application.